# how do i create a tab in a tabpanel onclick?

Tags: extjs, tabs, onclick

I have an actioncolumn in a grid. I used to open a window after i clicked on this but now do we want to open a new tab in the tabpanel instead of the windows. This is the tab i want to generate when someone clicks on the actionpanel:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel2', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
alias: 'widget.mytabpanel2',

closable: true,
title: 'Report {name}',
activeTab: 1,

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Reference',
                        labelAlign: 'top'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'From',
                        labelAlign: 'top'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'To',
                        labelAlign: 'top'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'tbfill'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Open report'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Save report'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Export report'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Refresh data'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                title: 'Grid',
                forceFit: true,
                store: 'resultStore',
                columns: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'ccuDesignation',
                        text: 'CCU Designation'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'carrierName',
                        text: 'Carrier Name'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'dataPackageName',
                        text: 'Data package name'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'bytesRx',
                        text: 'bytesRX'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'bytesTx',
                        text: 'bytesTX'
                    }
                ],
                viewConfig: {

                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Chart',
                dockedItems: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'chart',
                        height: 250,
                        animate: true,
                        insetPadding: 20,
                        store: 'resultStore',
                        dock: 'top',
                        axes: [
                            {
                                type: 'Category',
                                fields: [
                                    'ccuDesignation'
                                ],
                                position: 'bottom',
                                title: 'CCU Designation'
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'Numeric',
                                fields: [
                                    'bytesTx'
                                ],
                                position: 'left',
                                title: 'Bytes'
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'Numeric',
                                fields: [
                                    'bytesRx'
                                ],
                                position: 'left',
                                title: 'Bytes'
                            }
                        ],
                        series: [
                            {
                                type: 'line',
                                xField: 'x',
                                yField: [
                                    'bytesTx'
                                ],
                                smooth: 3
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'line',
                                xField: 'x',
                                yField: [
                                    'bytesRx'
                                ],
                                smooth: 3
                            }
                        ],
                        legend: {

                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

i have read this at sencha:

```
// tab generation code
var index = 0;
while(index < 3){
    addTab(index % 2);
}

function addTab (closable) {
    ++index;
    tabs.add({
        title: 'New Tab ' + index,
        iconCls: 'tabs',
        html: 'Tab Body ' + index + '<br/><br/>' + Ext.example.bogusMarkup,
        closable: !!closable
    }).show();
}

Ext.createWidget('button', {
    renderTo: 'addButtonCt',
    text: 'Add Closable Tab',
    handler: function () {
        addTab(true);
    },
    iconCls:'new-tab'
});

Ext.createWidget('button', {
    renderTo: 'addButtonCt',
    text: 'Add Unclosable Tab',
    handler: function () {
        addTab(false);
    },
    iconCls:'new-tab',
    style: 'margin-left: 8px;'
});
```

But i don't have the var tabs in my script. So how can i add the tab to this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyViewport', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

layout: {
    type: 'border'
},

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                id: 'tabs',
                activeTab: 1,
                region: 'center',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridpanel',
                        title: 'Reports',
                        forceFit: true,
                        store: 'ReportsStore',
                        columns: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Name',
                                text: 'Name'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Type',
                                text: 'Type'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'Description',
                                text: 'Description'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'queryFields',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e) {
                                            addTab;
                                            alert('clicked');
                                        },
                                        altText: 'Open report',
                                        icon: 'img/report-arrow.png',
                                        tooltip: 'Open report'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        viewConfig: {

                        },
                        dockedItems: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'toolbar',
                                dock: 'bottom',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'tbfill'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        iconCls: 'addReport',
                                        text: 'Add report',
                                        listeners: {
                                            click: {
                                                fn: me.onButtonClick,
                                                scope: me
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
},

onButtonClick: function(button, e, options) {
    Ext.create('MyApp.view.addReport').show();
}

});
var tabs = Ext.getCmp('tabs');

function addTab (closable) {
alert('yes');
tabs.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyTabPanel2'));
 }
```

How can i do this? I work with extjs designer 2

Comment: What version of EXTJS are you using?

Comment: i am using version 4.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that first view you've shown above, you are creating another tabpanel not an individual tab. If you tried to insert that into the tabpanel that you defined in your viewport you would have a tabpanel inside of another tabpanel. I don't think that is what you are trying to do.

You could create that first view above as an `Ext.tab.Tab` which contains the gridpanel or just create it as the gridpanel itself and include the tab config options in your `add` method call. To answer your question about referencing the tabpanel when you don't have it defined as a variable: you should just give it an `id` config (e.g. `id: 'tabs'`) and then you can use `Ext.getCmp('tabs')`. For example:

```
// a piece of your viewport config
Ext.applyIf(me, {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            activeTab: 1,
            region: 'center',
            id: 'tabs', // <-- include this config
            // other configs...
```

Adding the tab could then be done like this:

```
// get a reference to the tab panel
var tabs = Ext.getCmp('tabs');

// if you create the view as a gridpanel you could do it like this
tabs.add({
    title: sometitle,
    iconCls: someicon,
    closable: yayOrNay,
    items: [Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyGridPanel')]
});

// OR if you create the view as an Ext.tab.Tab which already contains the gridpanel
tabs.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyTab'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it in ff and get a "add is not a function" error or a "tabs is not defined"

Comment: @TobyJustus If you added the `id: 'tabs'` config to the tabpanel that is defined in the viewport above, then it could only be that you are calling `tabs.add` before the viewport has finished rendering. Can you post the code where you call `tabs.add` and update the other code snippets with the changes?

Comment: Hey Geronimo, i edit my code. I added the id and placed the code you suggested in the bottom. I guess it is the wrong place

Comment: Try putting the `var tabs = ...` inside of your addTab function. Also it looks like you are still adding a second tabpanel as a tab of your first tabpanel. Is that what you are trying to do? Or do you want to just add the grid as a tab?

Comment: Thanks for your help Geronimo. I put it inside the function and it works perfect! Last thing now is the store i will need to make dynamic :)

Answer (score 0):

Read And Use Following Code:

```js
function allExpenseTypeReport(){
    var reportByExpenseType=Ext.getCmp("reportByExpenseType");
    if(reportByExpenseType==null){
     reportByExpenseType = new Ext.tm.reports.ExpenseTypeReport({
        title:WtfGlobal.getLocaleText("ec.reportbyexpensetype"),
        layout:'fit' ,
        closable: true,
        iconCls:'pwnd tabreportsWrap',
        id:"reportByExpenseType"
     });
        Ext.getCmp('as').add(reportByExpenseType);
    }
        
     Ext.getCmp("as").setActiveTab(Wtf.getCmp("reportByExpenseType"));
     reportByExpenseType.doLayout();   
}







 Define Here:

Ext.tm.reports.ExpenseTypeReport = function(config){
    Ext.apply(this, config);
    Ext.tm.reports.ExpenseTypeReport.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
   
  Define your Code Here:
};
```